# How to make a dictionary value the key of another value?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an ajax POST that sends a dictionary from javascript to my Flask back-end like this:

```
{'output[0][description]': ['Source File'],
 'output[0][input]': ['Some_document.pdf'],
 'output[1][description]': ['Name'],
 'output[1][input]': ['Ari'],
 'output[2][description]': ['Address'],
 'output[2][input]': ['12 fake st']}
```

So I am trying to reorganize it on the back-end to look like this:

```
['Source File']:['Some_document.pdf'],
['Name']:['Ari],
['Address']:['12 fake st'],
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should reorganize your API to use proper JSON. Instead of indexes and keys inside the keys, use a nested structure of lists an objects.

Comment: My man! That solved about 100 other issues too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem : You can't use a `list` as the key of the `dict` because it's not hashable.

You could use the regular expression module (`re`) to examine each key to determine if it conforms to the expression

```
output\[(\d+)\]\[description\]
```

for each one that does, find the corresponding key

```
 output[$1][input]
```

put them together in the final `dict`.

The following is a sketch:

```
import re

P=re.compile('output\[(\d+)\]\[description\]')

inp = {'output[0][description]': ['Source File'], 'output[0][input]': ['Some_document.pdf'],
       'output[1][description]': ['Name'],        'output[1][input]': ['Ari'], 
       'output[2][description]': ['Address'],     'output[2][input]': ['12 fake st']}

out = {}

for key in inp :
    m = P.fullmatch(key)
    if m :
        out[inp[key][0]] = inp['output['+str(m.group(1))+'][input]'][0]

print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Klaus D.'s comment, you need to reorganize your API to use JSONs, that would simplify things but until then the following solution would be a lot faster than using regex and deliver the expected output

```
i=0
for key,val in inp.items():
    if i<3:
        print(f"{inp['output['+str(i)+'][description]']}:{inp['output['+str(i)+'][input]']}")
        i+=1
```